# What's the deal with Daniel's city level in SimCity Buildit?

Tags: simcity-buildit

I have been playing SimCity Buildit for a long time, and I realized that the level of Daniel's city rises when I level up. Same for the population. For example, when I was in level 16, Daniel's city level is 25. But when I'm in level 20, Daniel's city level is 30. Is there a pattern for Daniel's city's level and population to rise every time I level up?